# How to validate IdentityServer4 access tokens through introspection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am implementing a protected api via AccessToken released by IdentityServer4. Now my question is this, when from my client I make the call to the API with the Bearer token in the header, is there the possibility of recovering this value and validating it by calling the introspection endopint? No self-validation with key like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // base-address of your identityserver
            options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";

            // if you are using API resources, you can specify the name here
            options.Audience = "resource1";

            // IdentityServer emits a typ header by default, recommended extra check
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
        });
```

Is there any library that does everything in authorization middleware via Dependency Injection or do I have to do everything by hand? I tried to look around, but it seems that the only libraries refer to the reference token and not the access token passed as Bearer.
Thank you

Comment: Oauth2Introspection perhaps?: [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection) and [Docs](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#identitymodel-aspnetcore-oauth2introspection)

Comment: A thousand thanks. I knew about the IdentityModel package but not this extension. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into `OnMessageReceived` event and validate the token yourself:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddJwtBearer(
        options => {
            options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context => {
                var accessToken = context.Token;

                // inject a custom token validator
                var tokenValidator =
                    context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenValidator>();
                var ok = await tokenValidator.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken);
                if (!ok) {
                    context.Fail("Invalid token");
                }
            };
        }
    );
```